# identify/merge adjoining cells within an [] range array in order to limit the #ranges within the [] range array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a google sheet script that

1. Protects the sheet, then
2. Creates a range of all "formula" cells in the worksheet, then
3. Creates a [] of all worksheet cells that are NOT formulas (aka not in the formulas range), then
4. Unprotects all cells in []

```
function protectFormulas() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let up = [];
  let protection=sh.protect();
  const range = sh.getDataRange();
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  formulas.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c == '') {//if not a formula then add range to up
         up.push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1));
      }
    });
  });
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(up);//unprotect ranges in up
}
```

However
Since "up" only has "individual cell" ranges, I would like merge all adjacent cells together within "up" in order to limit the #ranges within it.

Is there any way to do that?

#### Why do I want to do this?

It's a very large sheet with a lot of formulas and blank space

- Limit the operations of the script, if possible , since it takes a loong time to run.
- Having individual cell ranges slows down the opening/closing of the protected page function
- because the protected sheet is a template that is going to be duplicated several times. I wrote another function that duplicates the sheet with the protections intact which is obviously running really slow because of the above.
- the sheets have to be protected is because there are other users that are going to be interacting with the sheets. They will be entering information into some of the non formula cells (which is of course why sensitive parts of the sheet need to be protected)

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to merge the ranges?  The original reason for writing the script was to identify all of the ranges that don't have formulas and then to unprotect them.  It does that.  It would probably be possible to write a script to condense the number of ranges by figuring out which ones are adjacent but it seems like a lot of work or at least a lot thought and I don't want to do it unless you have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: Yes, is the reason you are doing it to limit the number of operations the script needs to do? Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: Hi Cooper & Ian.. There are a couple of reasons. Because it's a very large sheet with a lot of formulas and blank space ...One is to limit the operations of the script, if possible , since it takes a loong time to run . The second is that having individual cell ranges slows down the opening/closing of the protected page function

Comment: Also in terms of context - the protected sheet is a template that is going to be duplicated several times. I wrote another function that duplicates the sheet with the protections intact which is obviously running really slow because of what we're talking about

Comment: And lastly, the reason that the sheets have to be protected is because there are other users that are going to be interacting with the sheets.  They will be entering information into some of the non formula cells (which is of course why sensitive parts of the sheet need to be protected)

Comment: In terms of modifying Coopers loop function, I think it's just a simple matter of adding another loop within the loop before posting each range to the up array. I was going to try to tackle it myself but I've got three kids and I honestly just don't have the focus/brain power right now :-(

Comment: Sorry I don't mean simple, I meant simply. Obviously some hard thought would have to be put into counters, output format, etc

Comment: Can you post an example of the sheet in question? AFAIK Cooper's idea is to take the array of cells that need to be protected and reduce it. I.e `[A1,A2,A3]`  becomes `[A1:A3]` . I'm not sure how this ties in with your `loop within a loop` comment though. Depending on the structure of the sheet, the above approach may be feasible, but it may not make things better at all. If you have such stringent protections, then maybe you are better off using forms or a webapp.

Comment: Can I share the sheet with yourself and Cooper privately?  ..by my ```loop loop``` I was just imagining a way to create the up[] ranges in a single sweep, but Cooper's suggestion of redefining up[] ranges (as a secondary function) is probably the better approach

Comment: Not privately, It has to be public. If its sensitive data then maybe make a copy with dummy data. I don't know how extensive this data is, but if its short then post a table into your answer. Another question about the data though: Are all the protected ranges in a certain column or row? Can't you just define which columns or rows will have formulas and then just protect the whole column/row?

Comment: Ok here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AoKabebvJd6qa5Hk10IzSGfkMeqCemzbXFN8W0QoQRA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: re: your question - as you will see, the data is extensive and there is no simple col/row pattern

Comment: I believe you want an implementation of a flood fill algorithm. On top of the flood fill, you will then need to divide the identified "formula regions" into optimal rectangles to represent the minimum amount of ranges, which is not a "simple" problem. This will make the script run faster but depending on how many times you want this script to run, it may not be worth it. Would be an interesting exercise though. I would try implementing something yourself and then posting a new question if you get stuck with your particular problem, and you would be better to tag it as an algorithm question.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your perspective.